# error when updating paper theme in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, themes, icon-themes

I've  paper theme PPA added and when I do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the below error, I'm 18.04.1 LTS also I Don't know how to add `--force-overwrite` option to apt which is available in dpkg:

```
Unpacking paper-cursor-theme (1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1) over (1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu17.10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/paper-cursor-theme_1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/Paper/cursor.theme', which is also in package paper-icon-theme 1.5.721-201808151353~daily~ubuntu18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/paper-cursor-theme_1.4+r696~daily~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I skip a particular upgrade as  well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I using paper `cursor.theme` at the time of installing, as a result, it was throwing an error that It cannot overwrite it. just changed the cursor theme to something else, then update, it will now get installed.